# configure own iterator for class php?

Tags: php, class, iterator

I have a class Foo, I need to do :

```
$foo = new Foo();
foreach($foo as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

and define my own method to iterate with this object, exemple :

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar = [1, 2, 3];
    private $baz = [4, 5, 6];


    function create_iterator()
    {
        //callback to the first creation of iterator for this object
        $this->do_something_one_time();
    }

    function iterate()
    {
        //callback for each iteration in foreach
        return $this->bar + $this->baz;
    }
}
```

Can we do that? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the [\Iterator](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.iterator.php) or [\IteratorAggregate](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.iteratoraggregate.php) interface to achieve that.

A simple example of what you're trying to achieve using the \IteratorAggregate and \Iterator interfaces (I've left out the \Iterator implementation details, but you can use the PHP doc to see how they work) :

```
class FooIterator implements \Iterator
{
    private $source = [];

    public function __construct(array $source) 
    {
        $this->source = $source;
        // Do whatever else you need
    }

    public function current() { ... }
    public function key() { ... }
    public function next() 
    {
        // This function is invoked on each step of the iteration
    }
    public function rewind() { ... }
    public function valid() { ... }
}


class Foo implements \IteratorAggregate
{
    private $bar = [1, 2, 3];
    private $baz = [4, 5, 6];

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new FooIterator(array_merge($this->bar, $this->baz));
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();

foreach ($foo as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: ok, but can I have a control to put my own code at creation of the iterator? How/where put my code?

Comment: I've updated my answer to match what you want -- if I understood correctly

Comment: yes, but why not overide ArrayIterator with custom children class and overiding just constructor? I will test, thx.

Comment: Because inheritance is evil ? :p Whatever solution works for you, my answer is just one way of doing things, and shows you how to use both interfaces.

Comment: inheritance is THE concept of POO. It's a better way, I don't need reimplements all methods, I just overide like : `class MyIterator extends ArrayIterator
{
   public function __construct($array=[])
   {
      parent::__construct($array);
      echo 'test'; //DO what I need here
   }
}` and it's works.

Comment: Ever heard of *composition over inheritance* ? ;) but as I said before, whatever works for you :)

Comment: In fact, after benchmark test, Iterator as evil. The perf is disastrous... I will not use that^^