# Return items and method chaining in php

Tags: php, method-chaining

One thing I have noticed from laravel is that you can get the items and chain the functions. How is that implemented in laravel? Let's take an example here

While getting data from model you can often do something like this
 `Model::get($id)->toArray();`

But if you enter only `Model::get($id)` then also it returns the data. How has it been implemented like this? I want to make method like this but the problem I have faced is that if I `return $this` then I can perform other actions but I don't get any data.Whereas If I return data I can't perform chaining.

If anyone could provide me an example and some explanation of how it's done then it would be great.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215352/configure-own-iterator-for-class-php may provide some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clases as object properties and also have conversion magic methods associated with them. inside the class of the object property you provide the methods that you chain and the magic method is called automatically by php when you attempt to use the value alone. For example:

lets say you have a class Foo

```
class Foo {
    var $value;

    public function __construct($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
    //the magic method __toString is used when you attempt to use the strval of
    // an object instance of this class
    public function __toString() {
        return strval($this->value);
    }
    function toArray(){
        return [
            'value' => $this->value
        ];
    }
}
```

and a class Test

```
class Test{
    static $foo;
}
```

if you inicialize `Test::$foo = new Foo('var');` then you can use method chaining as you shown in you example:

```
echo Test::$foo; //will echo "var"
print_r(Test::$foo->toArray()); //will echo "Array ( [value] => var )"
```

references here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring